# Angular lazy loaded module child route doesnt work on page reload/refresh

Tags: routes, lazy-loading, page-refresh, angular8

I have mutliple lazy loaded modules in my angular application where trying to use child route but doesnt work on page reload/refresh

works fine on click function, navigates to expected component, but on page refresh it doesnt work for localhost:4200/port-move/overview.

localhost:4200/overview - this works on refresh . Where It can be corrected to work for approach -> localhost:4200/port-move/overview . Can anyone please help out

Routes in Main Rouitng module (app-routing.module.ts):

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'search-uploads', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'port-move', loadChildren: () => import('./modules/routes/port-move/port-move.module').then(mod => mod.PortMoveModule) },
  { path: 'change-card', loadChildren: './modules/routes/change-card/change-card.module#ChangeCardModule' },
  { path: 'search-uploads', loadChildren: './modules/routes/search-uploads/search-uploads.module#SearchUploadsModule' },
  { path: 'inventory-recovery', loadChildren: './modules/routes/inventory-recovery/inventory-recovery.module#InventoryRecoveryModule' }
];
```

Routes in Port-move/(one of the lazy module):

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: PortMoveComponent },
    { path: 'overview', component: PortMoveOverviewComponent }
]
```

Click function to navigate to Port-move-overview component with port-move as parent and overview as child

// Navigates to Port Move Overview

```
   navigateTo() {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/port-move/overview');
    }
```

Comment: Got any solution for this?

Comment: changing base href to <base href='./'> causes this issue.

Answer (score 6):

changing base href to `<base href='./'>` causes this issue! use

Thanks.

Comment: In other words, change base href to `<base href='/'>`